# Git clone works but git fetch time-out occurs

Tags: git, github, npm

I'm configuring Jenkins build server, I just want to do this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd" install --production --msvs_version=2013
```

One of the packages is https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git/

This error message appears when running npm install:

```
npm WARN package.json AppServer@1.18.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json AppServer@1.18.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json AppServer@1.18.0 No license field.
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git) fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production" "--msvs_version=2013"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Jenkins\jobs\AppServer-NodeJS-Modules\workspace\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried adding `git clone https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git/` command before the npm install command, xmldom is cloned into my workspace successfully.

This is my final script:

```
git config --global http.proxy myproxy-here
git config --global https.proxy myproxy-here
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

git clone https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git/

"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd" install --production --msvs_version=2013
```

Why does git clone work fine while git fetch couldn't connect to the server?

Comment: It works for me. Can you please post your script when you do `git fetch`?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra I see git fetch in the log. Here: npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git)

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git)
```

is not a git command. If this is what you are using in the code, then you need to change it.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yaronn/xmldom.git
git fetch -a origin
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But how do I change it? It get called inside npm install command.

Comment: I'm not capable of answering about configuring npm install. I encourage you to ask a new question related to `how to configure npm install`.

Comment: That's a log statement, not necessarily the command being executed.